# Javascript selector with wildcard

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

What is a wildcard I could use to select everything on the page which has this selectorId? `aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_13-9"`  The selectorId is dynamically created.  The `13` part of the selectorId is different every time the page is loaded.

This is what I have tried: `var lineAmounts = document.querySelectorAll('[aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_" + * + "-9"]');` and that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of multiple [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

If you want to select all elements where the attribute `aria-describedby` starts with a certain string you can first select it using the `^=` operator. Combining with the `$=` operator you can limit the selection even further and define how the end of the attribute should look like.

```js
const prefix = 'gridx_Grid_';
const suffix = '-9';

const collection = document.querySelectorAll(
  `[aria-describedby^="${ prefix }"][aria-describedby$="${ suffix }"]`
);

collection.forEach( element => console.log( element.innerText ) );
```

```html
<div aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_13-9">Text 1</div>
<div aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_10-10">Text 2</div>
<div aria-describedby="gridx_Grid_11-9">Text 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the selector string:

```
[aria-describedby^="gridx_Grid_"][aria-describedby$="-9"]
```

which will search for an element whose `aria-describedby` attribute starts and ends with the desired string, but it would be more reliable to iterate over all elements with `aria-describedby` and find the one which matches, just in case there are elements which start and end with those substrings but have something other than just digits in the middle:

```
const element = Array.prototype.find.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('[aria-describedby]'),
  element => element.getAttribute('aria-describedby').match(/gridx_Grid_\d+-9/)
);
```